# Android problem

Tags: android

Hi iam working on android getting the following problem for my login but i didn't got my mistake... The error notice is the application has been terminated unexpectedly

my code is

```
 package layout.program;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Tablelayout extends Activity{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tablelayout);
}
}
```

**tablelayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView"     android:id="@+id/textView1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>
</TableRow>

 </TableLayout>
```

[image: snapshot of logcat and emulator]

Comment: it is showing the error : the application has been terminated unexpectedly

Comment: check logcat and see the exception and post that..

Comment: what is Exception it shows in the logcat?

Comment: logcat is not showing any thing... what to do?? iam editing my question with snapshot of emulator and logcat.... Logcat is showing empty screen

Comment: Click on the device tab and select your emulator there and after that your log cat will load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Cleaning your Project..
By Selecting the Project and then go to top project option and then select clean.
and then select OK..

Sometimes Changes are not made in R.java...Thats y this error comes

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine at my end..please look in your code if there is anything which is causing the exception..Try to debug with debugger....

Comment: i tried it and its showing like this Source not found : A:\AndroidSDK\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar has no source attachment

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your code or xml, so it has to be an error in your manifest.
As this application is just a stub, why not do this:

- Create a new Android project, call it anything you like.
- Call the activity 'TableLayoutActivity'
- Put your tablelayout.xml into the layout folder.
- Change the automatically generated code in TablelayoutActivity.java to set the content view from **setContentView(R.layout.main)** to **setContentView(R.layout.tablelayout)**

This should work, then have a look at the manifest in the new project, to see where you went wrong in your original project.

Answer (score 0):

change the class name and try again,also check if the activity name mentioned in the android manifest is correct.